# Drupal error when accessing sites: Can't get hostname for your address

Tags: drupal

I'm getting the following error when trying to access sites on my server through the browser.  I can `ssh` to the server and I tried running a flush hosts command but that didn't do anything.  The host in question is in the `mysql` user table and has a username/password and all relevant privs.  This issue appeared since an office move and the server was switched back on.  I can only think it of being a network issue of some sort.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1042] Can't get hostname for your address in db_table_exists()
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check if the mysql hostname defined in `$databases['default']['default']['host']` of the Drupal `sites/default/settings.php` file is reached by the machine where drupal is running.

Try to connect to ssh and do a `ping` or a `telnet` with the hostname.

Instead of the hostname try using the ip address. Otherwise, if the hostname is not resolved, try adding it to `/etc/hosts` if you're on linux.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried to ping the hostname and it resolved so looks like a network issue.